# alarm receiver for multiple alarms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, repeatingalarm

I have a program that allows users to input three times for alarm, then at the appropriate time, display an alert.However, whenever i set the alarms, only the last one is being carried out.

So basically, the user inputs 1,2 or 3 then i carry out the number of time selection dialogs, then send those times to the alarm receiver. But only the last alarm is being carried out. Any help is appreciated. Apologies for length of code, it's very inefficient i know.

Alarm Activity snippet::

```
buttonSetTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(alarmNumInt == 1){
                tvSet.setText("");
                openTimePicker1(false);
                }
                else if (alarmNumInt == 2){
                    tvSet2.setText("");
                    openTimePicker2(false);
                    tvSet.setText("");
                    openTimePicker1(false);

                    }
                else {
                tvSet3.setText("");
                openTimePicker3(false);
                tvSet2.setText("");
                openTimePicker2(false);
                tvSet.setText("");
                openTimePicker1(false);
                }
            }
        });


    protected void openTimePicker1(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

          timePromptDia = new TimePickerDialog(
            AlarmActivity.this, 
            onTimeSetListener, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            b);
          timePromptDia.setTitle("Set Alarm 1 Time");  

          timePromptDia.show();

         }

    protected void openTimePicker2(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

          timePromptDia2 = new TimePickerDialog(
            AlarmActivity.this, 
            onTimeSetListener2, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            b);
          timePromptDia2.setTitle("Set Alarm 2 Time");  

          timePromptDia2.show();

         }

    protected void openTimePicker3(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

          timePromptDia3 = new TimePickerDialog(
            AlarmActivity.this, 
            onTimeSetListener3, 
            calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
            calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
            b);
          timePromptDia3.setTitle("Set Alarm 3 Time");  

          timePromptDia3.show();

         }

          OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener(){

          public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {       
           Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
           Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

           calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
           calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
           calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
           calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

           if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
            //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
            calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
           }
           setAlarm(calSet);
           //condition for other alarms

          }};

          OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener2 = new OnTimeSetListener(){

              public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {                   
               Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
               Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

               calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
               calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
               calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
               calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

               if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
               }
               setAlarm2(calSet);
               }};


           OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener3 = new OnTimeSetListener(){

                      public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                       Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                       Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                       calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                       calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                       calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                       calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                       if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                       }
                       setAlarm3(calSet);
                       }};

            protected void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), req, intent1, 0);
                  AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
                   alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                             targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 
                             TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24),
                             pendingIntent1);

                   tvSet.setText("Alarm 1 is set @ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" +" Repeat everyday\n");


            }

            protected void setAlarm2(Calendar targetCal2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  Intent intent2 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), req2, intent2, 0);
                  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
                   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                             targetCal2.getTimeInMillis(), 
                             TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24),
                             pendingIntent2);

                   tvSet2.setText("Alarm 2 is set @ " + targetCal2.getTime()+" Repeat everyday\n");
            }

            protected void setAlarm3(Calendar targetCal3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  Intent intent3 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), req3, intent3, 0);
                  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal3.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent3);
                   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                             targetCal3.getTimeInMillis(), 
                             TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24),
                             pendingIntent3);

                   tvSet3.setText("Alarm 3 is set @ " + targetCal3.getTime() + " Repeat everyday\n");         
            }   
}
```

And the broadcast receiver activity:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

     playSound();
     Toast toast;
     toast = Toast.makeText(arg0, "Time for Blood Glucose Testing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0); 
     toast.show();
     Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) arg0.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
     vibrator.vibrate(1000);

  }
 public void playSound(){
     ToneGenerator alertTone = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
     alertTone.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1, 1000);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the values of req, req2 and req3? These need to be different for each alarm.

Also, I don't think this will solve your issue, but you don't need to call set() & setRepeating() on AlarmManager, just one or the other.

Either call set() and reset the alarm yourself when the alarm occurs or let AlarmManager handle resetting by using setRepeating().

Comment: Amazing catch, i had each request set to 1 at some point in the program. Changed each to a different value and it works perfectly. Thanks alot mate!